# Expo start fails with "Unexpected end of JSON input" when attempting to run on android simulator

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

I have an expo app that, as soon as I launch on the android simulator, hangs at 99% Building Javascript Bundle and outputs in the console a very cryptic:

```
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I have tried:

- npm and yarn cache clear
- npm and yarn audit fix
- restart the simulator
- rm -rf node_modules .expo .tmp

Nothing seems to work, furthermore that single line error I have no idea where it comes from!

Is there any way to get more verbose logs from the metro bundler?

It's driving me insane this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your metro bundler log please?

Answer (score 6):

clearing expo cache(start with -c flag) worked for me

```
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a known issue. You may have to run `expo publish` to generate these missing data. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1746

I recommend setting your project to `unlisted` before doing so.